# Load html frameset code from memory to Java SWT browser

Tags: java, html, browser, swt, frames

I have a simple html editor written with SWT and it's Browser control. I would like to know if there is a way to load the code for html frame pages from memory, without saving the html file on the hdd?

Answer (score 2):

The code which are you looking for is one of the SWT Browser widget snippets. See [render HTML from memory](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet136.java).

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Snippet136 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String html = "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTML Test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) html += "<P>This is line "+i+"</P>";
        html += "</BODY></HTML>";

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Browser browser;
        try {
            browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        } catch (SWTError e) {
            System.out.println("Could not instantiate Browser: " + e.getMessage());
            display.dispose();
            return;
        }
        browser.setText(html);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

There are few others snippets which may became handy for you.. Check [SWT Browser's widget snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser).

Comment: Yes I know how to load html code form memory. The problem is that I want to load a whole html page from memory which has frames. The frames have links like <a src="page1.html">... <a src="page5.html"> - these refer to html files that I would need to save on hdd in a location familiar for my application. Now my question is, can I somehow change the links to the code could be loaded from memory...

Comment: May I ask, why are you using frames?

Answer (score 1):

Add one line in your in memory HTML will do the trick.

For example, assume your files `page1.html` etc. locate in your local computer at `C:/myHTML`, then you need add this to your in memory HTML string as below,

```
String html="<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTML Test</TITLE>"
            +"<BASE href=\"file:///C:myHTML\\/\" >"
            +"<HEAD>"
            +"<BODY><A src=\"page1.html\">Page1</A></BODY></HTML>"
```

This works for me on Win 7.